# How can I scrape TD Elements from a site?

Tags: r

I'm trying to scrape some data from this link:

http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT

Basically, I want to get the `td elements` from `div class="Mstart(a) Mend(a)"`.

```
library(rvest)
html <- read_html("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT")
cast <- html_nodes(html, "qsp-statistics .Fw(500) Ta(end)")
length(cast)
html_text(cast)
```

I really think these HTML elements are correct.

```
div data-test="qsp-statistics"
td class=".Fw(500) Ta(end)"
```

I guess I am not parsing the HTML correctly.  Can someone here jump in and help out?

It should look like this when done.

```
Market Cap (intraday) 5 472.17B
Enterprise Value 3  402.95B
Trailing P/E    29.08
Forward P/E 1   18.74
PEG Ratio (5 yr expected) 1 2.07
Price/Sales (ttm)   5.53
Price/Book (mrq)    6.72
Enterprise Value/Revenue 3  4.72
Enterprise Value/EBITDA 6   14.95
Financial Highlights    
Fiscal Year 
Fiscal Year Ends    30-Jun-16
Most Recent Quarter (mrq)   30-Sep-16
Profitability   
Profit Margin   19.42%
Operating Margin (ttm)  24.27%
```

Thanks all.

Comment: A usefull resource: [the vignette on using `rvest` with Selectorgadget](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html)

Comment: Thanks.  That's a cool little gadget.  I clicked on the table I want and I got this:
.Mend(a)

Comment: Thanks.  That's a cool little gadget, but I don't think it helps me much.  I clicked on the table I want and I got this:
.Mend(a)
The class is:
div class="Mstart(a) Mend(a)"

Under that, I see all the td elements that I wand to grab:
td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)"